# Commitment should be serious matter, please ask me to confirm before uncommiting

Tags: feature-request, area-51, confirmation, uncommit

When I commit to a proposal on Area51 it's done after careful thinking, not something that is done lightly.

[image] ([source](http://thewedding.jeronimo.co.uk/2009/02/15/our-rings/))

When I uncommit, I expect family and friends to ask me to reconsider:

> [image]

Please, at least a small confirmation box? Or friendly robot explaining the consequences?

Being serious for a moment, people sometimes put long comment when committing and might click Uncommit by sheer mistake, although it's easily "undoable" by committing again, it's irritating.

Comment: Proposed counselor dialog prompt: `You used to be so committed. Remember when you told [Proposal Name] "[Your commitment comment]"?  Do you no longer feel that way?  What changed?  How did that make you feel?`

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Make sure [the machine is on the lowest setting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbgyppGqBgg) first.

Comment: This just happened to me *again* - I accidentally clicked "Uncommit" when I meant to click "Share this." +1

Answer (score 2):

I like this Idea, but I also don't want it too hard. I recommend the following when you click on uncommit a dialog box pops up with an area for feedback a check box by 'are you sure' and buttons marked cancel and uncommit. Minimum lazy action is three clicks, so it's not too easy or too hard, but allows for full comment for feedback even if it is just I have a girlfriend, or @(some one I hate) has joined and has high rep and I won't have anything to do with a site that he might be a moderator at, followed by thirty pages of ranting.

Comment: It's gonna be hard to post 30 pages of rant with that cell phone you were using to post this.  Unless it's actually a computer and you were in a huge hurry to post. Wat?

Comment: Curse you dyslexia, you haven't seen the last of me!

Comment: Just ordinary JavaScript `confirm()` dialog would suffice, same like we vote to delete posts for example. (not our own :))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd From a users perspective the mechanism doesn't matter too much, but I think three is the right number of clicks.

Comment: Fair enough, let the devs decide if and when they take this into their hands. :)